# Azkaban job configuration per environment

Tags: configuration, continuous-integration, batch-processing, azkaban

I plan to use the Azkaban https://azkaban.github.io/ for running batch jobs. According to CI ideas we have few environments like dev, test, stage, production and of course job should have different configuration for each environment.

According to Azkaban documentation http://azkaban.github.io/azkaban/docs/latest/#job-configuration Azkaban allows for replacing of parameters whenever a ${parameter} is found. And solution looks like:

```
system.properties
myFlow/
  dev.properties
  ....
  prod.properties
  foo.job

#system.properties
env=dev

#dev.properties
dev.database=localhost:2181

#prod.properties
prod.database=aws:port

#foo.job
some command --db ${${env}.database}
```

And later on each environment we can override the **env** variable. From my point of view this solution looks strange. Can I just say to Azkaban which property file should be used on environment?

What is the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 0):

An other approach can be found here https://github.com/azkaban/azkaban/issues/1545#issuecomment-339750417